# STM32F7 Discovery board vs dsp kit tms320c6713 vs Rasberry Pi?

Tags: dsp-core, reference-request, hardware-implementation, hardware, embedded-systems

We want to design dsp kit Labs for our undergraduate students for following tasks/topics.

1)Sampling and Quantization of real time Audio Signals on DSP Kit ; analyze the effect of Aliasing and Quantization Noise

2)FFT Algorithm with Radix-2 implementation on DSP Kit

3)FIR and IIR filters implementation on DSP Kit TMS320C6713 for real time processing

On searching google for "dsp kit"i got two prominent results. STM32F7 Discovery board & tms320c6713.  Both use C language

6713 seems very old and so its support may not be easily available and STM seems a better option but i am confused because i read on ST web site that it is based on a microcontroller but we want and need digital signal "processor"

So what should we do? Can we use STM32F7 Discovery board for hardware Labs of dsp?Anyone here who is using this board for dsp Lab in any university?

Update: I am updating my question as i saw on google that some universities also use rasberry pi for teaching Labs of Dsp

I guess raspberry pi will be best option in this scenario ,since it is based on a processor, not microcontroller, also its programming language is python, which is much easier than C and it will be easier for students to grasp concepts

Comment: "we want and need digital signal processor": You need to explain what you *need* in functionality for us to be ableto help you. The difference between a DSP and a microcontroller is... actually, there's no sharp difference. You'd expect some features in a DSP, but it's likely an STM32F7 has those. If you use a raspberry pi, you can just as well use a laptop or desktop PC. It's really not clear what the actual requirements are that you have – you're just throwing together things you have or have seen online.

Comment: a microcontroller is also a processor; I think what you mean to say is "the raspberry Pi is based on an *application processor*"; but the difference between an application processor and a microcontroller is even vaguer. You'd expect things like a memory management unit from an application processore, but the SMT32F7 probably has that...

Answer (score 3):

Typically a DSP lab should better include both a Raspberry pi and an STM32F7x interacting with each other.

Raspberry Pi is a mini PC. It uses an ARM based multicore CPU at GHz range (with FPU) and dedicated GPU, dedicated camera port, HDMI and sound output, USB ports, ethernet port, and an Operating System to make use of them.

The most striking feature of RPI is that it has GPIO electrical pins available to make raw digital interaction with the PC. These GPIO pins enable various sensors, actuators, data grabbers, to be connected to the RPI computer in a safe and reliable multitasking software environment...

However, RPI is lacking real-time support. Its interrupt handler (though very efficient) may/will not respond on time to the time-critical tasks, such as uniform audio sampling through GPIO.

To learn about true embedded electronic systems you must get involved in an MCU based board, and nowadays STM32F7x is one of the best platforms for this. It has a powerful ARM based MCU (though not powerful as the RPI CPU). Some variants might even have an FPU. It can respond to interrupts on the microseconds range. It has development boards for easy conduction of various experiments...

However, STM32Fx is a complex MCU to begin with. Managing all of its features will be an overkill for a basic undergraduate DSP & Embedded Electronics lab course, especially if you focus on low level details of the MCU using assembly language or C. Then you may consider using a simpler MCU. Support for FPU should also be considered...

Comment: Could you please also compare it with TMS320C67 TI DSP boards? This answer could be very inspirable.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd TI or ADI also develop very powerful and "professional" DSP chips. Yet their development boards and non-commercial user support may not be as accessible as those from ST... Things might have changed though and you should consider using them as well...